# sed -a command not working

Tags: shell, sed

I tried executing sed command in my script to insert a text above another line, whenever I come across my search pattern. I tried the 'a' command to insert the text but I couldn't get it to work.

```
sed '/Splitter/a \ "help" '  fileList.out
```

sed: 1: "/Splitter/a \ "help" ": extra characters after \ at the end of a command

```
machine-1:Splitter machine-1$ sed '/Splitter  /"help" /a \ '  fileList.out
```

sed: 1: "/Splitter  /"help" /a \ ": invalid command code "

```
machine-1:Splitter machine-1$ sed '/Splitter  /"help" a \ '  fileList.out
```

sed: 1: "/Splitter  /"help" a \ ": invalid command code "

```
machine-1:Splitter machine-1$ sed '/Splitter/"help"/a \ '  fileList.out
```

sed: 1: "/Splitter/"help"/a \ ": invalid command code "

```
machine-1:Splitter machine-1$ sed '/Splitter/help/a \ '  fileList.out
```

sed: 1: "/Splitter/help/a \ ": extra characters at the end of h command

```
machine-1:Splitter machine-1$ sed '/Splitter/a \ '  fileList.out
```

//File List

./Splitter/View

./Splitter/App

./Splitter/Util

./Splitter/main

./Splitter/Check/SplitImage

./SplitterTests/SplitterTests

./Splitter/SplitterITests

```
 machine-1:Splitter machine-1$ sed '/Splitter/a \ '  fileList.out
```

Answer (score 1):

The `a` command expects a `\` followed by a *newline*, then followed by text.

So the command should be:

```
sed '/Splitter/a\
"help"'
```

See also the [`sed` man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1).

Comment: GNU sed supports the single-line format as an extension.

Comment: I need to get this command work in shell script. So couldn't use the 2 line command.

Also the above command doesn't overwrite the file, just prints the output in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

To insert your text **above** the matching line, use the `i` command :

```
sed '/Splitter/i \
"help"
' fileList.out
```